# SSRS Stop RunningValue On Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, linechart

I am creating a line chart to show sales prospecting data.  I have 4 sets of values: Monthly Revenue at 100% confidence, Monthly Revenue adjusted to actual confidence %, Yearly Revenue at 100% confidence, and Yearly Revenue adjusted to actual confidence %.  I'm using a RunningValue() function to calculate the "Yearly" values, both 100% and adjusted, which are separated as a Series Group on each year.  The RunningValue is working perfectly, but I would like the line to end at the end of the year (or series), rather than plateauing through the rest of the graph.  I'm thinking using an expression on the Pick Color selection, so that if the Year is greater than current running year, set it to No Color, but I'm not sure how to write that expression.

[image: chart example]

The highlighted yellow areas are what I would like to remove.

A minor supplemental question is, can I eliminate the doubling up of the legend that occurs from the Series Group separation, which I need to use because I want the separate line rather than having a drastic drop between years.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to your running value expression so that it evaluates the year. I would use this on the value rather than the Color.

```
=IIF(YEAR(FIELDS!YourDateField.Value) <= YEAR(TODAY), <YOUR RUNNING TOTAL EXPRESSSION> , NOTHING)
```

Comment: That's not working for what I need.  I need the 2015 line to stop at the end of 2015, then have the 2016 start and and run for 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Use de 'Field Scope' in the RunningValue() expression. This way, the ruuning 'resets' every year.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!MonthlyRevenue.Value,sum,"NameOfYearField")
```